# Proxy breaks browser auto reload in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy

When I use "npm run dev" react stops auto refresh the firefox on any change in any folder in my client side.

Something I realized is if I remove the "proxy" property in my package.json in my client it fixes the problem, how can I fix it without removing the proxy property?

server package.json:
[image]

client package.json:
[image]

Comment: I sometimes receive the same error about proxy. In that case I just refresh the page, and the proxy error usually goes away, and then the front-end app loads and responds to changes. Does refreshing the page solve the problem for you?

Comment: This is not the problem I talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it by hard code the proxy into any of my axios request but I think there should be a better solution.